# Summation of hypergeometeric series

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I was solving a question on hypergeometric, I have been able to solve  up to this part and need a simplification.

$$ P(x_1)={_{13}}C_{x_1}/_{52}C_5\sum_{x_2 = 0}^{x_2=5} {_{13}}C_{x_2} \times _{26}C_{5-x_1-x_2} $$
How do I simplifying this, I have tried to expand but I don't think its helping. NOTE: $C$ is the combination.
A guideline to this will be appreciated.